# AJAX call to SpringBoot controller causes CORS error

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, spring-boot

I am using AJAX to pass a JSON to my controller. But I am not able to do so as I am getting a CORS error as follows:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at *........* from origin 'null' has been
>   blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass
>   access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is
>   present on the requested resource.

Here is my Javascript and embedded AJAX call:

```
database.on('child_added', function (snapshot) {
        var data = {};
        data["CaptainName"] = snapshot.val().CaptainName;
        data["CookName"] = snapshot.val().CookName;
        data["LogicalConditions"] = snapshot.val().LogicalConditions;

        $.ajax({
          headers:  { 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' },
          type: "GET",
          contentType: "application/json",
          url:"my-localhost/application/print",
          data: JSON.stringify(data),
          dataType: 'json',
          cache: false,
          success: function(){
            console.log("Successfully sent payload")
          },
          error: function(e){
            console.log("Error:" , e)
          }
        });
```

Here is my controller:

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*", allowedHeaders = "*")
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/application")
public class AppController
{
    @PostMapping("/print")
    public void print(@RequestBody String st)
    {
        System.out.println(st);
    }
}
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: do  you have same issue on any browsers ?

Answer (score 0):

following configuration may need to be done in the backend. Paste this codein one of your @configuration classes.  For example SecurityConfiguration.java class.

```
 @Bean
        public FilterRegistrationBean corsFilter() {
            UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
            CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
            config.setAllowCredentials(true);
            config.addAllowedOrigin("http://localhost:3000");
            config.addAllowedHeader("*");
            config.addAllowedMethod("*");
            source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
            FilterRegistrationBean bean = new FilterRegistrationBean(new CorsFilter(source));
            bean.setOrder(0);
            return bean;
        }
```